# Flutter problem on web on init changeNotifierProvider

Tags: flutter, dart, web, provider

Do you have an idea of the problem here ?

It work well on Android and IOS but i get this error on chrome

Is it the param 'read' the problem ?

[image: flutter code for provider setup]

[image: flutter code for the BaseViewModel of all ChangeNotifier]